# How to give dynamically created buttons actions for each one

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

first time posting here. I'm using a loop to create 3 buttons, but my problem is assigning the button actions to each button. My button listener/action code only works on the last button created :(

I tried to target buttons by the name that I gave them ($navButton.name = "button" + i) but that threw up an undefined error for button1.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm an AS3 noob :"(

```
function createNav(){

    for (var i:Number = 0; i < myXMLArray.length; i++)
    {
        $navButton = new NavButton();
        $navButton.name = "button" +i;
        $navButton.x = i * (SIZE + SPACING);
        $navButton.y = 179;
        addChild($navButton);
        trace("$navButton.name = "+$navButton.name);
        trace("button 1 = "+button1);

        //trying to give the 3 buttons a simple rollover/click action:

        $navButton.buttonMode = $navButton.buttonMode = true;
        $navButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, navAction);
        $navButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function() {$navButton.nextFrame();});
        $navButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, function() {$navButton.prevFrame();});


        //thought I could control via calling the $navButton.name
        //button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, navAction);
        //button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function() {button1.nextFrame();});
        //button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, function() {button1.prevFrame();});


        /*var traceText:TextField = new TextField();
        traceText.defaultTextFormat = a12;
        traceText.x = i * (SIZE + SPACING);
        traceText.y = 181;
        traceText.width = 116;
        traceText.height = 20;
        traceText.text = myXMLArray[i].id;
        addChild(traceText);*/
    }

}

function navAction()
{

    trace("click");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add the buttons to an array ad access as such:

outside of the loop:

```
var buttons:Array = []
```

in the loop:

```
buttons.push(navButton)
buttons[1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, navAction);
```

This should be done outside of the loop if you are trying to add custom functionality to a single button. Naming the object doesn't give you an object with the **instance** name. To access it as you have above, you'd need to use:

```
var button1:NavButton
```

which would allow you to access as you have done. Using the name property you could use something such as:

```
if(navButton.name == "button1")
    navButton.addEventListener(Event.BLAHBLAH, DoStuff);
```

I strongly recommend against using anonymous functions as your event listeners. Instead use named functions and the target property of the event:

```
function handleButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var button:NavButton = event.target as NavButton;
    if(button)
        button.nextFrame()
}
```

While it might (probably will) function with the anonymous functions, it will be so much easier to debug if you use named functions.

As an aside, using the $ for your vars is generally bad form in AS3. [Here's the Flex SDK Standards](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions), which are excellent conventions for all AS3 programming.

Comment: Awesome! That worked thx :D

And thx for the tip about the function name and var naming too...